# Dynamically assign a variable to a cursor - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

In following function I have used a variable - `@day_code` inside a cursor and it get different values during the execution of a while loop.

```
    DECLARE @curr_date   DATE = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @curr_day    VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @day_code    VARCHAR(1)
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
    DECLARE @exist INT = 0

    DECLARE test_cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 1
        FROM work_cal_time wct
        WHERE wct.day_code = @day_code

    WHILE @cnt < 3
        BEGIN
            SET @curr_date = DATEADD(day, -1, @curr_date)
            SET @curr_day = DATENAME(weekday, @curr_date)
            SET @day_code =
                CASE @curr_day  
                    WHEN 'Sunday'    THEN '1'
                    WHEN 'Monday'    THEN '2'
                    WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN '3'
                    WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN '4'
                    WHEN 'Thursday'  THEN '5'
                    WHEN 'Friday'    THEN '6'
                    WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN '7'
                END

            OPEN test_cur
            FETCH test_cur INTO @exist
            CLOSE test_cur

            IF @exist = 0 CONTINUE

            SET @exist = 0
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
        END;

    RETURN(@curr_date)
END
```

But, it seems the value of the variable `@day_code` is not picked up by the cursor.
However, if I initialize `@day_code` instead of assigning a value dynamically it works fine.
i.e.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test]()
RETURNS DATE
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @curr_date   DATE = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @curr_day    VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @day_code    VARCHAR(1) = '1'
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0
    DECLARE @exist INT = 0

    DECLARE test_cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 1
        FROM work_cal_time wct
        WHERE wct.day_code = @day_code

    WHILE @cnt < 3
        BEGIN
            SET @curr_date = DATEADD(day, -1, @curr_date)
            SET @curr_day = DATENAME(weekday, @curr_date)

            OPEN test_cur
            FETCH test_cur INTO @exist
            CLOSE test_cur

            IF @exist = 0 CONTINUE

            SET @exist = 0
            SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
        END;

    RETURN(@curr_date)
END
```

How do I dynamically assign a variable to a cursor?

Comment: Please take a look at [DATEPART(DW, <date>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: Functions like this are very inefficient, especially when you use a cursor inside. This could be quite easily be rewritten as a non-cursor version.

Comment: It works fine. When I debug, although '@day_code' has the correct value, it's not passed into the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `WHILE` loop to this:

```
WHILE @cnt < 3
    BEGIN
        SET @curr_date = DATEADD(day, -1, @curr_date)
        SET @curr_day = DATENAME(weekday, @curr_date)
        SET @day_code = DATEPART(dw,@curr_date)

        OPEN test_cur
        FETCH test_cur INTO @exist
        CLOSE test_cur

        IF @exist = 0 CONTINUE

        SET @exist = 0
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END;
```